# Image View problem

Tags: android, android-imageview

```
ImageView img;
TextView tv;
Parser p= new Parser();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cover);


    new AsyncTask<Void, Double, Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            while (true) {
                publishProgress(Math.random());
                SystemClock.sleep(3000);

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Double... values) {


            p.myHandler();
            img.setImageBitmap(p.bitmap);
            tv.setText("Artist : " + p.artist + "\n" + 
                       "Album : " + p.album + "\n" + 
                       "Song : " + p.title + "\n");
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

and also

```
p.bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(image).getContent());
```

but the image doesn't always show. The image appears and disappears randomly can you help me please?

Comment: do u get any errors in the stack trace?

Comment: You got bitmap proper????? please check with System.out.println("Bitmap :: " + p.bitmap);

Comment: You probably shouldn't do all of that logic inside the decodeStream method in one line.  The way you have it, you not only are unable to debug any problems (which you're currently having) but you have no way of handling failure.  When downloading a remote URL is part of your logic, you are almost always guaranteed to have cases where this fails, and it's a good idea to always have code for handling failures and optionally logging them, retrying, etc.

Comment: Samir when I use System.out.println("Bitmap :: " + p.bitmap); When it shows the bitmap -- Bitmap :: android.graphics.Bitmap@47de3cd0 and when it doesn't show Bitmap :: null

Comment: So I shouldn't use BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imageURL).getContent());??

Comment: OK That problem When your Bitmap is null then Image cant set..

Comment: I have similar issue on the Android 2.1. Sometimes image wasn't downloaded, but I found a different stream class which helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), there is a bug in the previous versions of `BitmapFactory.decodeStream`. It exists at least at the Android 2.1 SDK.

This class fixes the problem:

```
class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                  int ibyte = read();
                  if (ibyte < 0) {
                      break;  // we reached EOF
                  } else {
                      bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                  }
           }
            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }
        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}
```

And image should be downloaded so:

```
//I'm not sure whether this line works, but just in case I use another approach
//InputStream is = (InputStream)new URL(image).getContent()
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(imageUrl);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
//Use another stream
FlushedInputStream fis = new FlushedInputStream(is);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
```