# android load sampled bitmap from url

Tags: android, bitmap, memory-efficient

Im trying to load bitmaps efficiently from url, but somehow in end im getting empty imageview. Everything is working if decoding from resource.

```
try {
    InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
    mIcon11 = decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(in, 200, 200);
}
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
}
```

.

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromStream(InputStream in, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
}
```

Comment: It is reproduced in old versions of Android like 2.1?

Comment: No, im using 4.1.2 emulator at the moment.

Comment: Anyway try to wrap your InputStream by the stream from another my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7320747/image-view-problem/7321866#7321866. It can help with bitmaps that are not always loaded.